# Position absolute breaks my layout

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-animate

I'm trying to use ngAnimate to create transitions for my views, however i found that it needs the views to have the position property set to absolute to be able to overlap, my problem is that when I apply the position absolute, the layout loses the width and the height.

Here's how It looks like with It's default position (yes, they're on Spanish, sorry about that):

[image]
And here's how It looks like with position absolute:

[image]

and the code goes like this:

index

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-12">
    <div class="slideLeft" ng-view></div>
</div>
```

the view

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <label class="fixcolor"><strong>Agregar nuevo registro</strong></label>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <!-- it loses the layout here when loading with ng-include -->
    <div ng-switch="currentStep">
        <div ng-switch-when="1">
            <div class="slideLeft" ng-include="'ViewsAngular/NuevoProducto/paso1.html'">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="2">
            <div class="slideLeft" ng-include="'ViewsAngular/NuevoProducto/paso2.html'">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="3">
            <div class="slideLeft" ng-include="'ViewsAngular/NuevoProducto/paso3.html'">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the css

```
.slideLeft{
position:absolute;
}

.slideLeft.ng-leave        {
    -webkit-animation:slideLeftLeave 1s ease-in;
    -moz-animation:slideLeftLeave 1s ease-in;
    animation:slideLeftLeave 1s ease-in;   
}
.slideLeft.ng-enter         {  
    -webkit-animation:slideLeftEnter 1s ease-in;
    -moz-animation:slideLeftEnter 1s ease-in;
    animation:slideLeftEnter 1s ease-in;    
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideLeftLeave {
    from { left: 0 }
    to { left: -100% }
}
@-moz-keyframes slideLeftLeave {
    from { left: 0 }
    to { left: -100% }
}
@keyframes slideLeftLeave {
    from { left: 0 }
    to { left: -100% }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideLeftEnter {
    from { left: -100% }
    to { left: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes slideLeftEnter {
    from { left: -100% }
    to { left: 0 }
}
@keyframes slideLeftEnter {
    from { left: -100% }
    to { left: 0 }
}
```

I think this has something to do with the divs not expanding with dynamic content when using position absolute, but how can I do this overlapping behaviour without using absolute position?

Comment: I am not quite sure without a demo, but do not apply position absolute on `.slideLeft` instead apply t only when needed, i.e ex:- `.slideLeft.ng-leave, .slideLeft.ng-enter{position:absolute;}`

Comment: Well, that's pretty close, but there's a weird effect when it changes from absolute to relative, the width gets cut really fast. It gets almost unnoticeable when i reduce the animation time, though

Comment: That is because you would need to provide a width 100% or whatever it is.. SInce you positioned it absolute.Do you have a demo? Here is a quick demo, http://plnkr.co/edit/EKvZ5Db6S0Gl9wIbPj2d?p=preview

Comment: I tried to create a demo but i couldn't, now the div that is entering gets in too soon (the div with -leave doesn't get completely out of the window before the entering div appears). I think this is really close to what I'm looking for anyways

Comment: I added the width 100% as an animation and it looks better now, thanks a lot mate! :)

Comment: So this was not the exact issue I've had. But indeed when setting to absolute the width may need to be set to 100% in such cases